# From ACH direct debit to Prepaid card?

Tags: savings, bank-account, deposits, checking-account, ach

I am searching for solution how to be direct debited (ACH) to personal or business bank account where those funds would arrive (deposit) to prepaid card? The solution must meet all three of the following conditions:

- must be able to request direct debit of my funds OUTSIDE the actual online banking application (ebanking)
- wouldn't need to apply for time consuming merchant accounts
- for those debited funds must be possible to arrive to someone else's (e.g. seller of the product, service provider who did something for me for a charge,...) prepaid card so obviously name on my bank account doesn't match with name on prepaid card

I managed to find some prepaid cards, even being issued free of charge, that accept deposit of ACH direct debited funds but unfortunately there is no 3rd party location where to request debit on MY bank account which means I would have to request within online banking. Therefore this is NOT solution for me since first condition isn't met.

Anyone?

Comment: Take a step back and state the problem you're trying to solve,  rather than jumping to a specific solution that may not exist in exactly that form.

Comment: It sounds like a formula for a scam. I really doubt you'd be able find such an instrument. Why do you need this?

Answer (score 3):

This would be exactly the sort of product that a thief would want, if they had got ahold of some account numbers and wanted to steal the money from those accounts, in a way that would let them spend it as conveniently as possible.

That should explain why I think it's unlikely that any such product exists.